# OpenSource API Gateway which can support the API Plans like rate limiting/Month, API key Generation etc..?

Tags: spring-boot, api-gateway

I was wondering if there is any OpenSource API Gateway which can support generating commercial API plans which consists of API Key, RateLimiting to API and other features?

If not, how reliable it is to create through the application logic. I am currently using Spring Boot, Java as part of my stack

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an open source API gateway in the Spring ecosystem, then I would suggest to look into [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway) which is highly extensible. Check out the [Spring Cloud Gateway Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/) that also describes how to build rate limiting and related features.

Comment: Is there any ready-to-use Open-source tool through which I can monetise the API's available.

Comment: I am currently see only APIGEE which fits my requirement and it is costly too..